# How to access object in array( Dynamic DataType) with foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic-data

[image]

[Big Picture](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1613922016269)

i have this dynamic object. it is an array of object. i want to do a foreach loop in this object array.

i can foreach for a single object like below

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<dynamic, dynamic> pair in jsonstaticobj1232)
            {
                dwt.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);

            }
```

but how to foreach loop in a obj array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreach loop for dynamic object in array.

```
foreach (dynamic dObject in mArray)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for(int=0;i<jsonstaticobj1232.Length;i++)
{

foreach (KeyValuePair<dynamic, dynamic> pair in jsonstaticobj1232[i])
        {
            dwt.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       List<string> layers = new List<string>();
       var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
                foreach (Dictionary<string,dynamic> key in dict["layers"])
                {
                    key.TryGetValue("name", out layersDic);
                    layers.Add(layersDic);
                }
```